# Best practices for distributing a Haskell application and updating it

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

## tl;dr

About a week ago I released the 0.1.0.0 package for my first non-trivial Haskell project. I want the executable to be easy to install and upgrade, even for non-Haskellers. In [the README](https://github.com/wincent/docvim/blame/1455c33bafced7c19d5f922c3c51e52d062e4d7a/README.md#L43), I suggested installing using `cabal install`. Is this a mistake?

## Context

I had heard of "Cabal hell", but didn't realize how darn hard it would be for users to upgrade a globally installed copy of the package, even when I conservatively did not actually change any version dependencies in the `.cabal` file. In the end, I went down a deep rabbit hole trying to update from 0.1.0.0 to 0.2.0.0. It warned me about breaking dependencies, I tried various incantations to force the upgrade or reset my local state, and wound up borking the system so hard that I had to reinstall the `ghc` and `cabal-install` Brew packages (this is on macOS) in order to get everything back to a state in which I could install and run again.

Alternatives:

- `stack install`: I was already using Stack to manage local development environment, but it seems to work pretty well for independent installs as well, as long as you have Stack installed first. (Just need to set up your `$PATH` appropriately.)
- Distributing a prebuilt binary: Would be nice and easy for end users, but at least on OS X, I'd need to worry about code signing and I don't even have an identity set up for that any more.

So, in my README right now I am mentioning both `stack install` and `cabal install`. But what is the 2016 best practice?

Comment: If users run into "cabal-hell" attempting to install your package it's not really your problem if you have specified your dependencies correctly. For installing an application cabal users can always use a sandbox if they run into package version issues. Both `stack` and `cabal` have their place in the Haskell ecosystem. I think the best practice is to make sure your application can be installed using either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having looked at your [`.cabal` file](https://github.com/wincent/docvim/blob/2318877ad9128376c1fd505a78509c5e22523975/docvim.cabal) I see that you don't have any bounds on your dependencies. You really should have at least lower bounds and preferably both lower and upper bounds.

As @Emanuel Borsboom mentioned, you can have `stack` fill in the version constraints for you when you upload a package to Hackage with:

```
stack upload --pvp-bounds=both
```

In fact, for *applications* I suggest including the `cabal.config` file generated by `cabal freeze` in the package:

```
cabal freeze
mv cabal.config cabal.config-sample
```

When running into trouble building legacy applications from Hackage I've often wished the authors had included this information. You can get
the `cabal.config` file for a particular snapshot at:

```
https://www.stackage.org/{RESOLVER}/cabal.config
```

And in your `stack.yaml` file I would use a standard LTS version rather than a `nightly-`. Supposedly they will never get deleted. On the other
hand you'll be helping out your users by reducing the number of snapshot
directories they have to maintain.

Comment: Funnily, I had a `cabal.config` but [I removed it](https://github.com/wincent/docvim/commit/5ad9b0f4cdc) because I figured it wasn't really needed under Stack, and under Cabal I thought it might be contributing to Travis build failures like [this one](https://travis-ci.org/wincent/docvim/jobs/137999458). I was also [using the lts resolver](https://github.com/wincent/docvim/commit/06abd8de13238dbcd5f9ec5f26b543640be6dd4f) until a while back. As you can see, blindly thrashing around banging pots together in the kitchen without really knowing how to cook.

Comment: The nightly snapshots will not be deleted, although using LTS if you don't need anything in nightly is a good practise.

Comment: You can also grab a `cabal.config` for your stack.yaml's resolver from stackage.org.  For your current snapshot, you'd use 'https://www.stackage.org/nightly-2016-06-15/cabal.config'.  This means `cabal install` will use the exact same package versions as `stack install`.

Comment: Finally, you can leave out the constraints in your source `.cabal` file, but upload your package to Hackage using `stack upload --pvp-bounds=both`.  Stack will then automatically add upper and lower bounds based on the snapshot in the `.cabal` file uploaded to Hackage.

Comment: I've marked this answer as accepted, Erik, but it would be nice to incorporate the points made by @emanuel-borsboom too.

Comment: One gotcha: my package actually [got disabled in Stackage](https://github.com/fpco/stackage/pull/1618#issuecomment-226976704) because I applied both the advice to switch from a `nightly-`* to an `lts-*` resolver *and* the advice to use `--pvp-bounds both`. This made my package incompatible with the latest versions of the `lens` and `process` libraries, as specified in the nightlies. Fix I've gone with for now is to use an `lts-*` resolver, but `--pvp-bounds lower`. [This issue](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2262) might allow me to to use `--pvp-bounds both` in the future.

Comment: cabal.config-sample seems like an odd suggestion to me. The exact versions of which packages will be used in the build plan is entirely specified by the stack.yaml file. You can use `stack exec ghc-pkg list` to see what you've got already installed, and `stack build --dry-run` to see what still needs to be installed.